# WordPress Custom Theme Trouble

Tags: wordpress

So, I'm building a custom theme in WordPress.  This is my first time building a custom theme and everything is going well.  All my loops work and my code seem to be fine.  But when I click on a link to another page it get this error message.  "This webpage has a redirect loop"
Im not sure why this is happing.

I'm Building a Portfolio theme and I have a work page that list all the artist work.  That page is on work.php.  So the title of the work links to a more detailed page about the project.  The link goes to the single-work.php file.  But the link is not working just saying "This webpage has a redirect loop".(like i said before).

I am working locally on MAMP

Solutions I have Tried:

Flush the Permalinks 
Clear the cookies and cache
Make sure the permissions of your files are correct.

---- I have tried them all no luck------

code for work.php

```
    <?php 

/*

    Template Name: Work Page

*/




get_header(); ?>


<p>This is the work.php file</p>

<?php 

    $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'work'
        );

    $the_query = new WP_Query(  $args );


?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ): while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ;?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    <?php the_field( 'description' ); ?>
    <hr>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <p>There are no post or pages here</p>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

code for single-work.php:

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>


<p>This is the single-work.php file</p>

<?php if ( have_posts() ): while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <hr>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <p>There are no post or pages here</p>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

If you need more information just let me know!
any Advice would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the content of work.php and single-work.php

Comment: are work.php and single-work.php used as page templates or are you trying to link directly to these files?

Comment: I Added the code.  And Im using them as page templates.